# How do I sort the migration script folder in a ascending fashion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

How do I sort the migration script folder in a ascending fashion (i.e. I want the recently created scripts to come at the bottom when I do a `ls -l` command). Currently its coming in a mixed fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Rails root directory, `ls -ltr db/migrate/`

Or within db/migrate, just `ls -ltr`

---

```
Jason-Kim-MacBook-Pro:composer jkim$ ls -ltr db/migrate/
total 152
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   194 Apr  1 11:20 20130212221628_create_templatings.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   230 Apr  1 11:20 20130212212402_create_locales.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   188 Apr  1 11:20 20130212210032_create_websites.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   270 Apr  1 11:20 20130206224119_create_speaks.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   176 Apr  1 11:20 20130206224111_create_languages.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   176 Apr  1 11:20 20130206224104_create_countries.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   233 Apr  1 11:20 20130107231329_create_imagedescs.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   276 Apr  1 11:20 20130107231313_create_textdescs.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   227 Apr  1 11:20 20121207002247_create_images.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   229 Apr  1 11:20 20121130213128_create_fields.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   240 Apr  1 11:20 20121130213101_create_templates.rb
-rw-r--r--  1 jkim  staff   248 Apr  9 18:38 20130329210956_create_varinstances.rb
-rw-r--r--  1 jkim  staff   181 Apr  9 18:38 20130329203628_create_variables.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff  1518 Apr 12 14:51 20130122211324_devise_create_users.rb
-rw-r--r--  1 jkim  staff   201 Apr 12 15:14 20130412213724_create_profiles.rb
-rw-r--r--  1 jkim  staff   257 Apr 17 10:35 20130417173202_change_data_type_for_value_in_varinstance.rb
-rw-r--r--  1 jkim  staff   140 Apr 17 14:27 20130417212708_add_latest_change_made_by_to_pages.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jkim  staff   489 Apr 17 14:27 20121130213117_create_pages.rb
-rw-r--r--  1 jkim  staff   177 Apr 19 14:59 20130418182926_add_locking_attributes_to_pages.rb
```

Comment: Works just fine for me. Can you post the result of you doing `ls -ltr`?